# Applying conv2d frame by frame in keras to a video input

Tags: keras

I want to apply Conv2D followed by AveragePooling2D to each frame separately to a video input in Keras. The video size is (60,32,32,3) - 60 time frames, 32x32 frame size and 3 color channels.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16,3, input_shape = (60,32,32,3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size = 2))
```

The above code gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer average_pooling2d_10 is incompatible with the layer: expected 
ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 45, 30, 30, 16)
```

What is a fix to this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If input is video, then it good practice to use Timedistributed layer along with Conv2D.

Consider a batch of 16 video samples, where each sample is a `32x32 RGB` image with channels_last data format, across 60 timesteps. The batch input shape is `(16, 60, 32, 32, 3)`.

You can then use TimeDistributed to apply the same Conv2D layer to each of the 60 timesteps, independently:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(60, 32, 32, 3))
conv_2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv_2d_layer)(inputs)
```